# How to read the contents of .doc file into string in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, file

How do I read the contents of .doc file [**not from resource file**] into NSString in Objective-C?

I tried doing it in this way:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/User/home/Documents/config.doc"];
NSLog(@"Contents of file : %@",str);
```

OUTPUT:
-+-% [encoded format]

output is in encoded format

How do I solve this problem? Is it not reading from file the proper contents or am I printing it wrong?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The file you are using is probably binary, so when viewed as a string it will not work like you think.  You would need some sort of library or decoding function that would parse and display a binary .doc file.

Though you may have more luck with a `.docx` file which I believe is an XML based format that Word can save.